# Error when send email from Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, quickaction, send-email, action, screen-flow

I create the screenflow that calling Send Email Action
this flow will triggered from Action Button that I put on record page.
when I activate this flow and test to sent an email from record page
I got this following error

`Hmm, that didn't work. Check your internet connection and try again, or refresh the page. If the problem continues, ask your Salesforce admin to contact Salesforce Customer Support.`

I already try

- Test to send email and its work normal
- Check deliverability setting and its already set to able sending message to all email
- change send email action parameter with simple value (because I think maybe the error occur because email content itself

But still have the same error,
anyone can help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried debugging the flow ?

Comment: Yes,, the error still shown ... but there is no detail information on debug details section

Comment: please use [edit] and show how you configured the Send Email Alert action

Comment: I already fixed it. with trying this [comment](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Jedq5SAB). And got that my screen component should define default value for cc field address as its LWC element parameter. 
that causing the error. now its already work. Thanks all